# Nltk regexp_tokenizer doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I have a short question:

```
pattern = r"\w+(['-@&]\w+)*"
```

and

when I make

```
nltk.regexp_tokenize("lala/yaya", r"\w+(['-@&]\w+)*"  )
```

it gave

```
[u'lala/yaya']
```

I think I'm missing something. \w matches alphanumeric characters and I included ',-,@ and &. How come "/" in between can match anything?

I think output should be "lala", "yaya".

Can anyone explain? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is mainly because of location of hyphen  inside the character class `['-@&]` . It matches all the chars which are in the range from `'` to `@` (*`/` falls in this range*). Put  `-` at the first or at the last (*inside the character class*) or you could even do escaping, so that the hyphen won't act like a range operator.

```
[-'@&]
```

See the ascii value for each character [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

**Example:**

```
>>> re.findall(r"\w+(?:['-@&]\w+)*", 'lala/yaya')
['lala/yaya']
>>> re.findall(r"\w+(?:[-'@&]\w+)*", 'lala/yaya')
['lala', 'yaya']
```

Comment: change the location of hyphen `[-'@&]` or `['@&-]` or `['\-@&]`